# Remove white space from postgresql database columns not working

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, node-postgres

I'm trying to remove the whitespace that is trailing text in my PostgreSQL database, but nothing I try seems to work.

I have tried:

`UPDATE posts SET caption = TRIM(caption)`

`UPDATE posts SET caption = TRIM(regexp_replace(caption, '\s+', ' ', 'g'))`

Neither one of these has worked. I must have searched and tried several other things with no success.

I am using node-postgres in an express app to make API calls to retrieve my data.
After I update and I return my data via my API I get these results:

[image]

It's worth mentioning that if I do this:

`SELECT TRIM(TRAILING FROM caption)...`

This will remove the trailing whitespace. (yes, I have tried this on the update statement as well.)

Is there something else I can try?

I want to avoid adding TRIM to all of my columns that need it when there are a lot of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your "whitespace" chars could be vertical tab chars, which AFAIK are not "whitepace" chars.

Try using an *extended* characters in the regular `replace()` function:

```
update posts set caption  = trim(replace(replace(replace(caption, E'\v', ''), E'\n', ''), E'\r', '')))
```

or regex:

```
update posts set caption = trim(regexp_replace(caption, '[\n\r\v\f\t]', '', 'g'))
```

If this doesn't work, try inspecting each byte of your value to discover exactly what chars are in there:

```
select encode(caption::bytea, 'hex') -- display each character as hex
```

Comment: I should've specified that the data type I was using for these columns was `character`. I changed them to `text` and that seems to fix the issue.